# How to select varying count of items per colum value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with Postgresql.

I have a sql code

```
SELECT lp."RegionId", COUNT(w."Id") FROM public.workplace w
GROUP BY lp."RegionId"
```

that returns to me

```
RegionId | Count
1        | 3
2        | 12
3        | 5
```

I have table 'person'. Each person have RegionId.
So i for region 1 i want to select first 3 persons, for region 2 select first 12 persons, for region 3 select first 5 persons.

So how can i use it as subquery to table 'person'?

```
WITH (SELECT lp."RegionId", COUNT(w."Id") FROM public.workplace w
GROUP BY lp."RegionId") AS pc

SELECT * FROM public.person p
???????
limit pc."Count"
???
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `[INNER] JOIN` here

Comment: What determines the order of records in the person table to tell which is first, second, etc.?

Comment: Its primary key "PersonId". But actuall order is not necessery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY RegionId ORDER BY PersonId) AS rn
      FROM person) AS p
JOIN (SELECT RegionId, count(*) AS cnt
      FROM workplace
      GROUP BY RegionId) AS r ON p.RegionId = r.RegionId
WHERE p.rn <= r.cnt
ORDER BY p.RegionId, p.PersonId;
```